# Why compiler warns about resource leak?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, resource-leak

I cannot understand why compiler warns me about a resource leak (`Resource leak: 'conn' is not closed at this location`) in the following code:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DatabaseConnectionPool.getConnectionFromPool();
        // Some code
        try {
            // Other code
        } catch (final SomeException e) {
            // More code
            throw e; // Resource leak: 'conn' is not closed at this location
        }

    } catch (final SQLException | OtherExceptions e) {
        // Some more code
    } finally {
        try {
            // Another bunch of code
        } finally {
            DatabaseConnectionPool.freeConnection(conn);
        }
    }
```

Note that if I write it like this

```
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DatabaseConnectionPool.getConnectionFromPool();
        // Some code
        try {
            // Other code
        } catch (final SomeException e) {
            // More code
            throw e;
        } finally {
            DatabaseConnectionPool.freeConnection(conn);
        }

    } catch (final SQLException | OtherExceptions e) {
        // Some more code
    } finally {
        // Another bunch of code
    }
```

the warning is gone.

Comment: That is not a compiler warning.  You are using a tool to produce this warning and most likely it is a bug in the tool.

Comment: I think the finally block is the key

Comment: @PeterLawrey It is Eclipse Java built-in compiler, so it is indeed a compiler warning. But I think you're right, it is a bug in this compiler.

Comment: `final SQLException | OtherExceptions e` - what does it mean? (maybe I should study not only latest C++ but also latest java ;.. codes are evolving fast..)

Comment: @ikh This is a new Java 7 syntax to allow one catch to catch several exceptions at once.

Comment: @m0skit0 interesting.. but how it can be possible? how can compiler determine the type of `e` in compile time?

Comment: @ikh I don't know, I suppose you can always treat it as `Throwable`.

Comment: @m0skit0 it treats it as the closest common parent which could be RuntimeException or Exception.  It was added to Java 7 in 2011.

Comment: No assignment to `conn`? With some return-with-expression such a thing might be a legit problem. Within "Some more code" (maybe) and within "Another bunch of code" `conn` might be null.

Comment: @JoopEggen Good point, but no, those bunches of codes never return (I almost never return from the middle of a method) and `conn` is never reassigned there.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is quite dump. It probably cannot know that `DatabaseConnectionPool.freeConnection(conn)` will call `close` on the `conn`. I am not sure why the second example does not trigger this warning, but probably the feature is just not totally perfect and can yield false negatives. Basically, any resource should be closed by calling its `close` method directly at the place where the resource is acquired; this is the only way the compiler can figure out that you want to close it, it does not to inter-procedural analysis to check if a called function calls `close`.

With java7, you should consider using the try-with-resource statement; it is **the** encouraged way to handle any resources, i.e.:

```
try(Connection conn = ...){
   // Do something with conn

   // No close necessary here, done implicitly by the try statement
}
```

Your whole pattern of closing a connection by calling a method other than `close` seems flawed to me (it works, but I would strongly discourage its usage): Any resource should be able to close itself by calling `close`. If your resource requires `DatabaseConnectionPool.freeConnection` to be called to close it, you are violating java's resource contract. If you use the try-with-resource statement, you have no choice anyway: The statement will call `close` and not your method.

Comment: It definitely does know `DatabaseConnectionPool.freeConnection(conn)` calls `close`, this is why second example has no warning. I think its checking logic simply cannot handle the nested `try`. And thanks for the try-with-resource, I read about it but completely forgot to use it (I'm still mostly Java-6-minded).

Comment: @m0skit0: Just because the second example works does not mean that it knows that. The second example could be a false negative. But your guess could be true as well.

Comment: Well it works to explain both cases while yours cannot explain the second case; I will stick with it for now. Thanks for your help and your reminder of try-with-resource!

Comment: I upvote your answer but I cannot accept it as it is not the correct explanation in my opinion. PeterLawrey's comment is closest correct answer.

Comment: @m0skit0: What happens when you remove the `close` call in your `DatabaseConnectionPool.freeConnection` method? Does the second example then also issue the warning? If it then does, then you are right; if it doesn't, then I am right.

Comment: The `try(Connection conn = ...)` try-with-resource is great but I don't think that is the answer to the question.

Comment: In fact your test will only show that my explanation is not valid, but now both explanations will be tied as both cannot explain why example 2 works. EDIT: right, doesn't change, so my explanation is not valid neither. In any case your answer doesn't explain why the problem happens, neither does mine. Still not a real answer :)

Comment: @m0skit0: Nitpicking: Your question was why the compiler *does* warns about a resource leak. My answer does answer that: The compiler cannot look into the function. The question why it does *not* warn was not your main question ;).

Comment: Dude, really... Anyway, I'm not discussing this anymore because we're running in circles. Thanks again for your answer.